# $(window).resize only triggered on browser refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've read through numerous entries in SO about the jQuery window resize event and ways to get it to work - i.e.,

```
    $(window).on('resize',function(),
    $(window).bind('resize',function(),
    $(window).resize(function()
```

and for whatever reason, it's only working for me when the page is refreshed.

Here's my code:

```
$(function() {
  function checkWinSize() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 1120) {
      //Enable Click Handler
      $('#menu-top-inner nav > ul > li').click(function () {
        $(this).not('.menu-title').addClass('menu-on');
        $(this).children('.top-items').show();
      }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('menu-on');
        $(this).children('.top-items').hide();
      });
      $('#top-eg').click(function () {
        loadTopMenu(this, '/eyeglasses/all-prescription-eyeglasses.aspx #alphaLinks + div');
      });
      $('#top-sg').click(function () {
        loadTopMenu(this, '/sunglasses/all-sunglasses.aspx #alphaLinks + div');
      });
      $('#top-ps').click(function () {
        loadTopMenu(this, '/prescription-sunglasses/all-prescription-sunglasses.aspx #alphaLinks + div');
      });
      $('#top-cl').click(function () {
        loadTopMenu(this, '/contact-lenses/all-contact-lenses.aspx #alphaLinks + div');
      });
    } else {
      //Disable Click Handler
      $('#menu-top-inner nav > ui > li').click(false);
    }
  }
  checkWinSize();

  $(window).on('resize', function () {
    checkWinSize();
  });
});
```

EDIT: Here's the HTML

```
<!-- MENU TOP START ++ -->
<div id="menu-top">
  <!-- MENU TOP INNER START ++ -->
  <div id="menu-top-inner">
    <!-- NAV START ++ -->   
    <nav role="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li id="top-men"><span>Men</span>
          <div class="top-items">
            <asp:Literal ID="ltrlTopMenuMen" runat="server" />
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="top-women"><span>Women</span>
          <div class="top-items">
            <asp:Literal ID="ltrlTopMenuWomen" runat="server" />
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="top-eg"><span>Eyeglasses</span>
          <div class="top-items">
            <asp:Literal ID="ltrlTopMenuEyeglasses" runat="server" />
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="top-sg"><span>Sunglasses</span>
          <div class="top-items">
            <asp:Literal ID="ltrlTopMenuSunglasses" runat="server" />
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="top-ps"><span>Prescription Sunglasses</span>
          <div class="top-items">
            <asp:Literal ID="ltrlTopMenuRxSunglasses" runat="server" />
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="top-cl"><span>Contact Lenses</span>
          <div class="top-items">
            <asp:Literal ID="ltrlTopMenuContactLenses" runat="server" />
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="top-help"><span>Help</span>
          <div class="top-items">
            <asp:Literal ID="ltrlTopMenuHelp" runat="server" />
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- NAV END xx -->
  </div>
  <!-- MENU TOP INNER END xx -->
</div>
<!-- MENU TOP END xx -->
```

If I resize the window, the menus retain their click state from what was set at document load.  However, if I refresh the page, the correct click handler settings are activated.

Thoughts on what may be happening here?

UPDATE:  I changed the click handlers to use `.bind('click', function()` to be consistent with the change to `.unbind('click')` when I wanted to disable the mouse clicks.  However, the clicks are not re-binded if the click is unbinded.  Here's the new script (no HTML changes were made).  Also, I had to specify the exact click handler IDs to unbind (wasn't aware of this before).  Also, I checked to ensure there were no instances of `$(window).resize('off')` or other code that might be countering the resizing.

```
var eventsBound = false;
function checkWinSize() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 1120 && !eventsBound) {
    eventsBound = true;
    $('#menu-top-inner nav > ul > li').bind('click', function () {
      $(this).not('.menu-title').addClass('menu-on');
      $(this).children('.top-items').show();
    }).mouseleave(function () {
      $(this).removeClass('menu-on');
      $(this).children('.top-items').hide();
    });
    $('#top-eg').bind('click', function () {
      loadTopMenu(this, '/eyeglasses/all-prescription-eyeglasses.aspx #alphaLinks +    div');
    });
    $('#top-sg').bind('click', function () {
      loadTopMenu(this, '/sunglasses/all-sunglasses.aspx #alphaLinks + div');
    });
    $('#top-ps').bind('click', function () {
      loadTopMenu(this, '/prescription-sunglasses/all-prescription-sunglasses.aspx #alphaLinks + div');
    });
    $('#top-cl').bind('click', function () {
      loadTopMenu(this, '/contact-lenses/all-contact-lenses.aspx #alphaLinks + div');
    });
  } else {
    eventsBound = false;
    $('#menu-top-inner nav > ul > li,#top-eg,#top-sg,#top-ps,#top-cl').unbind('click');
  }
}
$(window).on('resize', checkWinSize);
```

**SOLVED:**

I was able to resolve this final issue by adjusting the condition for the bind check.  In the `} else {`, I changed that to `} else if ($(window).width() < 1120 && eventsBound) {` as the other was handling everything even when the window size was above 1120 but resized and the eventsBound was true.

Comment: `('#menu-top-inner nav > ui > li').click(false);` to "disable click handler" - Can you explain this please? Do you mean `.off('click')` or `.unbind('click')`?

Comment: @popnoodles, I changed this to `.unbind('click');`.
@matewka, I added the HTML.

Comment: What is your console telling you? If you've made the fixes as per matewka's answer, it could be that some JS simply stops JS from working because of an error. in Chrome, hit F12 then click Console.

Comment: @popnoodles, the console isn't reporting any errors.  However, it looks like the unbind is failing.  For example, when I open the window full the click is bound and the menus work properly.  When I resize the window below 1120px it still activates the menus.  However, when I refresh at the smaller size, the menus are now bound until I resize the window to a larger size.  Resizing back down does not unbind the click.

Comment: Once the click is un-binded, it doesn't get re-binded.  So it works when starting from the full screen and sizing down now but not the other way.  I'll edit my question above to include the new changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your *unbinding logic* is correct. To unbind a event handler in `jQuery` you should use

```
$('#menu-top-inner nav > ui > li').off('click');
```

### Additional things:

You don't have to wrap the `checkWinSize` function with an anonymous function. You can simply do

```
$(window).on('resize', checkWinSize);
```

Then generally, your code is inappropriate, because you're binding yet another `click` event handler every time you resize the window. Let's say your window is 1920px wide. Handlers are bound on page load. Then you resize it to 1600px. Handlers are bound again. That way they'll be called twice when the event occurs. I suggest using a flag. Like this:

```
$(function() {
    var eventsBound = false; //the flag
    function checkWinState() {
        if ($(window).width() >= 1120 && !eventsBound) {
            eventsBound = true;
            //bind the clicks
        } else {
            eventsBound = false;
            //unbind everything
        }
    }
    //...
});
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  This isn't working, however.  I did adjust the unbind event with `.unbind('click')` instead of `.click(false)`.  I removed the anonymous function from the window resize as well.  It still only fires on refresh versus resize.

Comment: +1 matewka and +1 @popnoodles, thank you both for your assistance here.  It helped me work through the issue and I've posted my updated code and solution above.

Comment: Happy New Year to you as well! :)